# Infinite scrolling compositional layout Swift

Tags: swift, uikit

I am making an app that is using compositional layout for the collectionview I'm having a carrousel layout that display elements horizontally.

```
let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(100), heightDimension: .absolute(100))
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
    item.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 2, leading: 2, bottom: 2, trailing: 2)
    let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(100), heightDimension: .fractionalWidth(1 / 3))
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
    group.contentInsets = .init(top: 4, leading: 0, bottom: 4, trailing: 0)
    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous
```

How can I achieve infinite scrolling meaning that every time we get the last element it goes back to the first element and continue to scroll? (for now it works, I can scroll element but every time the last element is displayed I have to scroll back the other way)

I have seen many way to achieve this with the old collectionview system, but I wanna keep using the new way please

Answer (score 2):

Maintain your datasource and return Int16.max or any large number and do simple modulo to get your item from datasource to dequeue reusable cell with your model

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

var sections: [Int] = Array(0...7)
var models: [[Int]] = Array(repeating: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], count: 8)

var sectionCellColors: [Int: UIColor] = [
    0 : .blue,
    1 : .red,
    2 : .green,
    3 : .yellow,
    4 : .magenta,
    5 : .brown,
    6 : .gray,
    7 : .black
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .cyan
    let layout = createLayout()
    collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: false)
}

func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { sectionNum, environment in
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(
            layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
                widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.2),
                heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1)))
        item.contentInsets = .init(top: 8, leading: 8, bottom: 8, trailing: 8)
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: .init(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .absolute(300)), subitems: [item])
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous
        return section
    }
    return layout
}

override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    if context.nextFocusedView?.isKind(of: UICollectionViewCell.self) == true {
        context.nextFocusedView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.purple.cgColor
        context.nextFocusedView?.layer.borderWidth = 2
    }
    if context.previouslyFocusedView?.isKind(of: UICollectionViewCell.self) == true {
        context.nextFocusedView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        context.nextFocusedView?.layer.borderWidth = 0
    }
}
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return Int(Int16.max)
//        return sections.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return models[section % sections.count].count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellID", for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = sectionCellColors[indexPath.section % sections.count]
    return cell
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to add 2 more additional images to your imagesArray like this:

```
guard let firstImage = images.first, let lastImage = images.last else { return }
images.append(firstImage)
images.insert(lastImage, at: 0)
```

So you get appropriate images dataSource.
We use **scrollViewDidScroll** method with UICollectionView to achieve infinite scrolling. But sections with **orthogonalScrollingBehavior** doesn't respond to this method, so you have to use **visibleItemsInvalidationHandler**

You can achieve this by the following code:

```
section.visibleItemsInvalidationHandler = { [weak self] _, point, _ in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    guard self.isHorizontalScrollingEnabled else { return }

    if point.x <= .zero {
        self.collectionView.scrollToItem(
            at: .init(row: images.count - 2, section: <your section index>),
            at: .centeredHorizontally,
            animated: false
        )
    }

    if point.x >= (groupWidth - section.interGroupSpacing) * CGFloat(images.count - 1) {
        self.collectionView.scrollToItem(
            at: .init(row: 1, section: <your section index>),
            at: .centeredHorizontally,
            animated: false
        )
    }
}
```

Notice that when you're ready to display data(i.e. get response with images), right after reloading data you have to call:

```
collectionView.scrollToItem(at: .init(row: 1, section: <yout section index>), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
isHorizontalScrollingEnabled = true
```

**isHorizontalScrollingEnabled**(it's initial value obvious equal to false) serves to prevent any calculations before your data is displayed and you actually need it because **visibleItemsInvalidationHandler** is called some times before you actually initiate scrolling.